# How frequently do cats lose their whiskers?

Tags: cats, biology, shedding, anatomy

Does anyone know how frequently cats lose their whiskers?  Is it natural shedding, like their hair, or is it much less frequent?

I ask because I have two cats and am randomly find a whisker here and there for the one cat.  I never find any from the other cat but his whiskers are darker and much closer in color to the color of his fur.  I'm thinking he may shed his whiskers, too -- but maybe I just never see them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuously (if slowly) shed and replaced; nothing to worry about.

I'm always amused by finding a whisker; I forget just how long they are compared to the cat until  I have one without the cat attached, and I find it interesting to ponder how that would scale up if large cat's whiskers were the same relative length.

Comment: Each whisker lasts several months, as well; I have a mostly black cat with all black whiskers above his eyes except for one, so it's very noticeable when that lone white one is shed, and it's infrequent that I spot him without it.